# Furnace short cycling at times

Tags: hvac

My furnace is short cycling occasionally, it will run fine for a day, then it will short cycle for a while, then run fine again for a day. I replaced the limit switch. I am going to replace the pressure switch. Can I replace a .59 wc pf with a .60 wc pf? And will that solve the problem?

Comment: Including the brand/model of the furnace would probably help. Also, you might want to look into what's causing the short cycle instead of looking to bypass it/band-aid over it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Its a comfortmaker cm8pn125j20a1. I hadn't even thought about by-passing anything. I am trying to replace parts that are faulty. I have been told that one part that could be faulty and could be causing the problem is the pressure switch, which is relatively inexpensive. My main question was is it OK to replace a .59 wc pf with a .60 wc pf, which is the closest size available at our local supplier.

Comment: When it's short cycling, observe the cycle. See what it is failing on.

Comment: "Short cycle" to me would mean that the call for heat is satisfied in a short amount of time (ie the furnace ran fine but is oversized for the demand). Your description seems to describe the cycle terminating early, ie the thermostat continuously calling for heat but the furnace cutting out early. A furnace built in the last 30+ years should have a control board, which should indicate the nature of the fault that caused it to quit early. Look for a flashing LED and for a decoder chart inside one of the furnace cover/doors.

Comment: It may be operating as designed.   You don't want wide temperature swings.  A few short bursts of heat is better to keep a steady temperature.  Is cold air hitting the thermostat immediately after the desired temp is reached?

Comment: Sometimes when it starts the inducer kicks in for a second or 2 then stops, it'l do that three or for times then codes  pressure switch open, Sometimes it starts inducer kicks in, pilot lights and goes off three or four times then codes soft lockout for exceeds ignition attempts, Then it will start go through everything and run just fine for a day or two. Then any combination of the above in any random order.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I replace a .59 wc pf with a .60 wc pf?

yes, .59wc = 0.021329 psi;  0.60wc = 0.02165psi

not enough to make any realistic difference and is insignificant in relation to operating conditions and design of your burner flue; its normal and common for replacement parts to vary like that in specification.

> And will that solve the problem?

only if that's the cause of the problem, as in the gasket sealing your burner and fan motor happens to leak after a bit of time causing the pressure switch to trip and shut off the burner which you notice and interpret as *short cycling*.  you would use a manometer teed in to the pressure switch hose to try and monitor when the burner "short cycles if it's because of the pressure switch, or a volt meter watching the electrical side of the switch.  Along with checking the entire intake & exhaust path.   It could be also the pressure switch hose if that's deteriorated or plugged.

How does an Air Pressure Switch work in a Gas Furnace - HVAC
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9a8ZPf-NAc

Furnace Pressure Switch Troubleshooting, pay attention at 9:30 in the vid, pressure switches themselves are often not the problem and just replacing them won't fix the problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zax02itYHkU

Comment: Sometimes when it starts the inducer kicks in for a second or 2 then stops, it'l do that three or for times then codes pressure switch open, Sometimes it starts inducer kicks in, pilot lights and goes off three or four times then codes soft lockout for exceeds ignition attempts, Then it will start go through everything and run just fine for a day or two. Then any combination of the above in any random order.